# JavaFX - Am I misunderstanding how to use KeyValues?

Tags: java, animation, javafx

```
KeyValue start = new KeyValue(enemy.translateXProperty(), 0);
KeyValue end = new KeyValue(enemy.translateXProperty(), 600);
KeyValue back = new KeyValue(enemy.translateXProperty(), 0);

KeyFrame startFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, start);
KeyFrame endFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), end);
KeyFrame backFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), back);

Timeline timeline = new Timeline(startFrame, endFrame, backFrame);
timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```

This is just some snippet from playing around since I'm on the animation section of the javafx book I've been reading, but I was wondering why it's not working. Basically, this is just supposed to make a circle goto the right and the left repeatedly. The KeyValue 'back' is supposed to take it back to the beginning, but it doesn't and the circle goes to the very right then spawns back to where it started instantly.

Am I misunderstanding something with KeyValues, or what? What's the problem here?

Comment: on the third ```KeyFrame``` the duration should probably be ```Duration.seconds(10)``` (i.e. a keyframe at 10 seconds) not 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Duration time` parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html#getTime--) of the [`KeyFrame` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/KeyFrame.html#KeyFrame-javafx.util.Duration-javafx.animation.KeyValue...-) takes time relative to the start of the animation, not relative to the last `KeyFrame`.

If you want to animate the `enemy.translateXProperty()` property from 0 to 600 during the first 5 seconds of the animation and animate it back to 0 during the following 5 seconds, you need to use `Duration.seconds(10)` as parameter for the constructor of the `back` `KeyFrame`.

```
KeyFrame backFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(10), back);
```

Note that for simply adding the reversed animation, you could also set `autoReverse` to `true`:

```
KeyValue start = new KeyValue(enemy.translateXProperty(), 0);
KeyValue end = new KeyValue(enemy.translateXProperty(), 600);

KeyFrame startFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, start);
KeyFrame endFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), end);

Timeline timeline = new Timeline(startFrame, endFrame);
timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
timeline.play();
```